# Access rights and security in odoo 10

Tags: odoo

I am applying access rights and security on group-user and group-manager whereas group-manager is working properly and showing the module on which it apply but on other hand group-user can't view the  module .

Comment: Could you give more details on what model or did you inherit any native odoo group? If possible show your code so we know what's wrong

Comment: Please add the group definitions (xml), the access rights (csv or xml) and the views, actions and menues for the custom model.

Comment: what?!! help us to help you some code please

Comment: i was missing to mention group-user alongside wit group-manager in menuitem 

here is new code i added 

<menuitem action="student_registration_action_student_views" id="student_registration_menu" sequence="50" name="Student Management" web_icon="students,static/description/web-icon.png" groups="students.group_manager,students.group_user"/>